# pulp program for the the following constraint min(a,b) > min(x,y)

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

Suppose for a moment that I have 4 variables a,b,x,y
and one constraint min(a,b) > min(x,y).

how can I represent this program in pulp python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok.  So, the first answer I posted (deleted) was a bit hasty and the logic was faulty for the relationship described.  This is (hopefully) correct!  ;)

`max()` and `min()` are nonlinear, so we need to linearize them somehow (with helper variable) and some logic to relate the 2 minima, which (below) can use a binary helper variable and a Big-M constraint.

in pseudocode:

```
a, b, x, y : real-valued variables
ab_min : real-valued variable
x_lt_y : binary variable, 1 implies x <= y, 0 else

M = some suitably large constant, depending on the max range of a, b, x, y
```

new constraints:

```
ab_min <= a
ab_min <= b
ab_min >= x - (1 - x_lt_y) * M
ab_min >= y - (x_lt_y) * M
```

Logic:

- We find the minimum of a, b with `ab_min`.
- We need "upward pressure" from the min(x, y)...  So we know that
  `ab_min` must be greater than *either* x or y, or possibly both.  For the "or"
  constraint, we use the binary logic above and multiply it by the
  "large constant" to make the other constraint trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I would reformulate this as:

```
z <= x
z <= y
z >= x - Mδ
z >= y - M(1-δ)
a >= z + 0.00001
b >= z + 0.00001
δ ∈ {0,1}
```

One extra binary variable δ is needed, and one continuous variable z. M is a large enough constant to be chosen with care.